# psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "max"

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

I changed the data type of a field **"max"** in my model from text to float and I got this error when I run python3 manage.py migrate after makemigrations. What's the solution please?

Running migrations:
**psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "max".**
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
**django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "max**

```
 my original model:
 class calculation(models.Model):
    fullname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    min = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    max = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

 my model after the change::
 class calculation(models.Model):
    fullname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    min = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    max = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: You probably at some point accidentally loaded the table header as if it were a data row, and so now have a value for the "max" column which is spelled 'max'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is related to the data that is already in the database for the "max" field. When you changed the data type of the "max" field from text to float, the existing text data in the field cannot be automatically converted to a float data type.

The solution is to do this migration in two steps:

First, create a new field (e.g. "max_temp") of type float in your model and update your code to use this new field instead of the old "max" field.
Then, create a data migration to copy the data from the old "max" field to the new "max_temp" field.
Then, remove the old "max" field and rename the new "max_temp" field to "max".
You can use the django built-in commands like python3 manage.py makemigrations --empty to add the empty migration, python3 manage.py add_field     to add the field and then write the migration function to copy the data from the old field to the new field in the migration file.

You can also use 3rd party libraries like "django-db-multitenant" to handle the migration in a more easy way, it will take care of the data migration and renaming the columns in the database.

It's important to have a backup of your data before doing any migrations.

Please note that this process can be complex and it's important to test it in a development environment before deploying it to a production environment.

Comment: You did not mention the actual cause of the issue which will not go away with above process. `select 'max'::float; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "max"`. The current `max` field has improper data in it and your "Then, create a data migration to copy the data from the old "max" field to the new "max_temp" field." will trip on that as well. You can automatically migrate text -> float if the text is correctly formatted. The existing data in the field will need to be cleaned up prior to any migration.